Prove there exists an $a\in I$ such that $(\sqrt[3]{2})^a$ is also an element of the irrationals
In my attempt, I chose $a = \sqrt{2}$ noting it was irrational, and which makes $\sqrt[3](2)^a =2^{\sqrt{{2}}/3}$, which I’m pretty confident is irrational, but I have no idea how to prove this.

What is $\mathbb{I}$?

Have a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem

If all rational then an uncountable number of irrationals exists. Assuming $I$ is an interval.

I represents the set of all Irrational numbers

You have had a couple of answers, Ryland. Any thoughts on either of them? Do you need any further explanation, or does one or the other settle matters for you?

I’m voting to close this question because OP is missing-in-action.

You’re right that $a=\sqrt2$ probably works. However, it is sometimes quite hard to show that a number is irrational directly. Let’s try to capture this idea of “almost any value for $a$ surely works.”
First, let’s get rid of the cube root. To do this, simply realize that every irrational is $3$ times some other irrational. Thus it suffices to show that there is a value for $a\in \mathbb{I}$ such that $2^a \in \mathbb{I}$.
Second, $2^x$ is a strictly monotone increasing function for $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Thus it is an injection.
Now, let us suppose towards a contradiction that no matter our value for $a$ irrational, $2^a$ is rational. This gives us an injection from an uncountable set to a countable set, contradiction.

User Malady has given an existence proof. User Bij2u gave a precise example, but then deleted the answer (which had an error). Here is a corrected version of that example.
Let $a=3(\log 2)^{-1}$. Then
$$
(\root3\of2)^a=2^{{1\over3}{3\over\log2}}=2^{{1\over\log2}}=e
$$
is irrational, so it remains to show that $3(\log2)^{-1}$ is irrational. It will suffice to prove $\log2$ is irrational. Suppose, to the contrary, that $\log2=p/q$, with $p,q$ positive integers. Then $2^q=e^p$. But $2^q$ is an integer, while $e^p$ is irrational (indeed, transcendental), since $e$ is transcendental. So, we have reached a contradiction, so the assumption that $\log2$ is rational was false.
